# Certifying a LoRa product for both EU868 and US915 MHz bands - are you allowed to toggle the frequency band in hardware?

Tags: rf, fcc

Suppose I'm manufacturing a product whose radio module is capable of 868 and 915MHz, and switching between the two can be accomplished in the firmware. I could therefore conceivably have a logical switch of some sort on my PCB that tells the product which frequency band it's supposed to operate in. Hooray, JIT manufacturing here I come!

However, for FCC certification is it allowable to have a physical switch that determines frequency band? Which of these are forbidden (if any?):

- Solder bridge on PCB
- Dipswitch on PCB inaccessible to end user, for assignment during manufacturing.
- Dipswitch on device interior accessible for technician during expedition/installation.
- Dipswitch on device exterior accessible for user (with instructions how to set the correct frequency so the device can communicate with the gateway).

I haven't been able to find any information on this subject just from internet search engines, but it's a hard set of keywords to get right.

Comment: @jsotola - OK, apologies. I wasn't aware. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to certify a product for both FCC and ETSI. As long as the end user cannot easily change it, you should be fine.
Generally, DIP Switches are not permitted for selecting frequency band, by the FCC and ETSI and most other national certification bodies.
Under FCC rules, You will have to prove that the end user cannot change the setting - It should not appear in the user manual, only in the technician/repair manual.
You should consult your certification lab.
You should also have different part numbers for different regions, even if the hardware is the same.